# Django model return groups

Tags: python, django

Let's say there's a Django model User who is assigned a type.

```
|id|name |type| 
|--|-----|----|
|1 | John| A  |
|2 | Doe | B  |
|3 | Jane| A  |
|4 | Mary| B  |
|5 | Jill| C  |
```

I want to query the User model so that it returns groups of users. Something like `Users.group('type',count=2)` I should get the models `[[@john,@jane],[@doe,@mary]]`. So basically I want to do a `group by` and `having` but still get the whole models.

I want django to let the underlying database do the querying and just load the necessary models without having to do it at the python side by loading all the models and doing a filter. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is such query set structure that allows you to group results like this. You should use `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: @ozgur: Make it an answer please so I could upvote it. Something like `.orderby("type")` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

As described by the Django docs, [the Django Query API filter method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) allows you to filter your queryset.

I *think* the best way to do this would be to do something like:

`user_groups = [User.objects.filter(type=group)[:2] for group in groups]`

I hope there is a better way because this will have to do a separate query for each type, but I don't know of one.